# Generic Type compatibility issue

Tags: typescript

With this code, I get a syntax Error at m1 and m2, that basically says: `Type 'T' is not assignable to Type 'boolean'` or `Type 'T' is not assignable to Type 'string'`

```
interface myMethod {
    <T>(b: T): myObject<T>;
}


class myObject<T> {

    constructor(private gg: T) {
    }

}

var m1: myMethod = function (b : boolean) {

    return new myObject(b);
}

var m2: myMethod = function (b: string) {

    return new myObject(b);
}
```

what can I do about that?

Comment: You might want to add which typescript version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature defined by `myMethod` is generic, so only a generic function can satisfy the signature, or one that replaces `T` with any:

```
var m1: myMethod = function <T>(b : T) {

    return new myObject(b);
}
// Works but I would not recommend id.
var m2: myMethod = function (b : any) {

    return new myObject(b);
}
```